# how to restrict drive videos that is in the device gallery in android

Tags: java, android

when I open gallery from my application, I want the videos that is stored in device and not in the drive.I used this code still its not working,it opens image too.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),REQUEST_TAKE_GALLERY_VIDEO);
```